# Code utilizing GD ending up in an error that "image cannot be displayed"

Tags: php, gd

My code is as follows:

```
<?php
session_start();
$img=imagecreatetruecolor(150,50);

$white=imagecolorallocate($img,255,255,255);
$black=imagecolorallocate($img,0,0,0);
$red=imagecolorallocate($img,255,0,0);
$pink=imagecolorallocate($img,200,0,150);
$grey=imagecolorallocate($img,150,150,150);
$blue=imagecolorallocate($img,0,204,255);
$redd=imagecolorallocate($img, 153, 0,0);
function randomString($length){
    $chars="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ023456789";
    srand((double)microtime()*1000000);
    $str="";
    while($i<=$length){
        $num=rand() % 33;
        $tmp=substr($chars,$num,1);
        $str.=$tmp;
        $i++;
    }
    return $str;
}
for($i=0;$i<=rand(1,5);$i++)
{
    $color=(rand(1,2)==1)? $grey:$white;
    imageline($img, rand(5,50),rand(5,50),rand(50,150) , rand(5,50), $color);
}
$ran=randomString(rand(3,6));
$_SESSION['captcha']=$ran;
imagefill($img,0,0,$redd);
imagettftext($img,14,7,23,27,$black,"fonts/times_new_yorker.ttf",$ran);
imagettftext($img,16,10,18,30,$white,"fonts/times_new_yorker.ttf",$ran);
header("Content-type:image/png");
imagepng($img);
imagedestroy($img);

?>
```

Yesterday this worked as expected. But now Firefox is showing a message:

> This image cannot be displayed, because this contains error.

When I searched for any solutions, it seems everyone is saying something about enabling GD. But in my code GD *is* enabled, and this very code worked perfectly up until this morning.

Can anyone help me to get a solution for this?

Comment: Please comment the line where you change the header. This will allow you to see the REAL php error. If there is one, we would love to see it :)

Comment: I've edited your question a bit, with some markdown and spelling changes. Please consider adding some details: is it *just* Firefox? What is the *exact* error? What happens if you strip out parts of your code, i.e. what is the *minimal* repro for this problem? Do you have links to those talking about "enabling GD"?

Comment: Thanks a lot for saving some to replay for this problem.................The good news is ,"My  problem is solved"...........Am really in a hurry for completing a project,very much depressed by this error,it took a lot of my time.The thing which irritated me was,it worked well yesterday,the sudden change hurt me a lot."The real problem in this code is  "'"$i  is not initialized  .Don't know why I forgot that ,may be due to the hurry............Well thank you friends...Find it by commenting header part.....A new lesson for me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image cannot be displayed, because PHP reports an error, and the `header('Content-Type: image/png')` tells it to show the page as an image.

To see the error, you should remove the following part:

```
header("Content-type:image/png");
imagepng($img);
imagedestroy($img);
```

or better yet, surround it with `if (!isset($_GET['debug']))` statement. That way you can append `?debug=1` to your URL and see all possible PHP errors, while the image stills display normally.

There are a few possible solutions why your code might have stopped working without changing it. My guess is that you tampered with environment somehow.

- `session_start()` needs to store session data in a directory on your local drive. Does your PHP have access to that directory?
- The font `fonts/times_new_yorker.ttf` could disappear.
- You could have moved the script to Linux machine, where letter casing matters. Are you sure the path to the font shouldn't have uppercase characters anywhere in it?

Also, just a couple of tips:

- You don't need to call `srand()`, it's initialized automatically. (I assume you come from C/C++ background).
- Instead of using `rand()`, you should use `mt_rand()` as it's faster and provides better randomness.
- Instead of using magic numbers, you should use meaningful expressions (for example, replace `% 33` with `% strlen($chars)`).
- Since you seem to display a captcha, consider matching `0` and `O`, `1` and `l` as the same "character", so that reasonable user mistakes are forgiven. (Pardon if you do it already.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for saving some to replay for this problem.................The good news is ,"My  problem is solved"...........Am really in a hurry for completing a project,very much depressed by this error,it took a lot of my time.The thing which irritated me was,it worked well yesterday,the sudden change hurt me a lot."The real problem in this code is  "'"$i  is not initialized  .Don't know why I forgot that ,may be due to the hurry............Well thank you friends...Find it by commenting header part.....A new lesson for me..

Comment: Well the sad is .......since the code worked well yesterday......thought it might be some system errors,so  I restored my os,some important datas gone.....                                                                                                                       But happy to know ,there are  friends like guys out there to look into my problem..........This is my first time in asking for help in net...............

Comment: Am doing a mini project on discussion forum(truly without any kind of professional support,well knows the basics of  php c/cpp   a little)......... well now I am stuck since my discussion forum  should be atleast provide the 1/3 facilities provided by phpbb like forums,have very little time and you know guys for any creative work on this topic ,a good research on all these forums is needed.Very much confused on the activities of moderators and the reputations and all the basic of ."If you like to share your knowledge about these forums ,please message me at savigms2@gmail.com.

Comment: Can you help me in  matching 0 and O, 1 and l as the same "character" through some simple codes.

Comment: @Sachin You're welcome. Regarding matching `0` and `O` - instead of comparing it like `$userInput == $_SESSION['captcha']`, you compare it character by character, like `$okay = strlen($userInput) == strlen($_SESSION['captcha']); if ($okay) { for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($userInput); $i ++) { if ($userInput{$i} != $_SESSION['captcha']{$i}) { $okay = false; break; } } }` and add necessary conditions for `$userInput{$i}` and `$_SESSION['captcha']{$i}`.

Comment: For example, instead of doing `$okay = false` right away when you know the characters mismatch, you can do something like `in_array($userInput{$i}, ['0', 'O']) && in_array($_SESSION[$captcha]{$i}, '0', 'O'])` and decide if it's `$okay` basing on the result. (Of course in order not to repeat yourself all the time, you should introduce a few variables instead of tryping the same stuff again and again.)

Comment: Regarding why it stopped working: possibly you enabled stricter PHP warnings (such as `E_NOTICE`) that were previously suppressed, or enabled outputting them to a browser (instead of server-side log files).

Comment: Ooops, thats right  I enabled E_ALL.Thankyou sir thankyou very much for your great support.